# Ask turtle to turn face other target depending on patch features

Tags: algorithm, netlogo

I'm stuck at this part of my code.

- I want to move my turtle under my control. I mean when it first reached a house, it must turn and move to another house.

In this code, it will move -10 5 which red patch and house shape here.
Now, **how can I tell this turtle ''you are here and you must go there''** !?

*(I use a red patch because I tried to move the turtle depending on patch but can't find any solution.)*

```
breed [cities city]
breed [flag person]

to setup
    clear-all
    set-default-shape cities "house"

    create-flag 1
    [ set SIZE 6 set shape "by" setxy -5 3 set HEADING 0 ]

    create-flag 1
    [ set SIZE 6 set shape "sel" setxy 12 5 set HEADING 0 ]

    create-cities 1
    [set color yellow set SIZE 2 setxy 8 2]

    create-cities 1
    [ set color yellow set SIZE 2 setxy -10 5]

    ask patch -10 5 [set pcolor red]
end

to go
    ask flag with [ shape = "by" ] [ facexy -10 5 forward 1 set HEADING 0 ]
end
```

---

### Update

I understand and tried this code from @jenB's answer and it's yet not moving as I want. Thank you for your interest, but there are two problems here that I tried to explain with this picture.

I've started a new question about this here:
[Turtles, patches and their moving sequentially from one patch to the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521102/turtles-patches-and-their-moving-sequentially-from-one-patch-to-the-next)

[image: img]

Comment: What programming language is this? Please, set the proper tags.

Comment: Thank you yacc! sorry for mistakes! :')
From NetLogo unbirth.


- I want to write independently from library to learn some  basic and cant find solution from dictionary or web. I hope you guys can help me! .

Comment: @yacc  I explain my question at  imgur.com/a/sres8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `turtles-on` in the NetLogo dictionary. From your other question, I know that you are trying to make your flags move sequentially from one house to the next. One way to do that is to have the flag store its target and simply change the target when it reaches one. Something like this (this will not work as it is incomplete)

```
breed [cities city]
breed [flag person]
flag-own
[ target
]

to setup
  clear-all

  create-flag 1
  [ set size 6
    set shape "by"
    setxy -5 3
    set target patch -10 5
    face target
  ]

  < other commands >
end

to go
  ask flag-on patch -10 5
  [ set target patch <next place you want it to go>
    face target
  ]
  ask flag with [ shape = "by" ]
  [ forward 1 ]
end
```

I also got rid of all your `set heading` commands. The command `face` turns the turtle so that `forward` is towards whatever the turtle is facing. The command `set heading` turns the turtle so that `forward` is in the direction given by the heading (for example `set heading 90` will make it move to the right if told to go forward).

Comment: Im sorry for answer late. I was on my work trip. I understand and tried this code and its move as not i want. thank you for your interest but there is two problem here and i tried to explain with this picture @JenB 

This is how this code work. ( Here im solve and understand the target and facing thank you! )  and how i want to move ( because i draw map and put  it behind this cities) 

-  https://imgur.com/a/sres8

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Move Towards Target Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.  It does exactly this, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right ! But there is some issue at this code. Because i want to move my turtle (flag) with specific point. For instance 

-start with 100k energy-
-lose '' x '' energy when you reach cities-
-go 1 -
-then 2 -
-then 3 , -
-when u re 3, die-
-while traveling [1,2,3] plot energy/time -

I can not reach my goal . Hope you guys help me! :'(

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question on that.